# Trigger callback after multiple rows are faded from table

Tags: jquery

I have a table and I want to fade out multiple rows and remove them, 
then when it has finished removing them, I need a callback to start working on the next batch of rows.

I know why my code is not working, $trs.fadeOut is getting called once for every row that is removed. So finaliseNextBatchBookings ends up getting called multiple times.

I am not sure how to trigger finaliseNextBatchBookings after the last of the $trs has been removed

```
var $trs = $checkboxes.closest('tr');

                        numBookingsFinalised += $trs.length;

                        $trs.fadeOut("normal", function () {
                            $(this).remove();
                            finaliseNextBatchBookings(numBookingsFinalised, finaliseBookingsCompleteCallback);
                        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the promise object returned by the animation

```
$trs.fadeOut("normal").promise().done(function () {
    $trs.remove();
    console.log('done')
    finaliseNextBatchBookings(numBookingsFinalised, finaliseBookingsCompleteCallback);
});
```

```js
var $trs = $('tr'),
  numBookingsFinalised, finaliseBookingsCompleteCallback;

$('#hide').click(function() {
  $trs.fadeOut("normal").promise().done(function() {
    console.log('done')
    $trs.remove();
    finaliseNextBatchBookings(numBookingsFinalised, finaliseBookingsCompleteCallback);
  });
});

function finaliseNextBatchBookings() {
  console.log('called')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="hide">Hide</button>
<table>
  <tr><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>4</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I tried your original post, but because I was removing the rows it was removing the promise too. You edit works great, Thanks